# Is there any standard functionality for creating a flattened view of a map with a container as the mapped_type?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Is there any standard functionality to create a range/view over all pairs?  The following code illustrates the view I am looking to create:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> m{{"Foo", {1,2}}, {"Hello", {4,5}}};
auto view = ???;
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> v{view.begin(), view.end()};
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> out1{{"Foo", 1}, {"Foo", 2}, {"Hello", 4}, {"Hello", 5}};
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> out2{{"Hello", 4}, {"Hello", 5}, {"Foo", 1}, {"Foo", 2}};
assert(v == out1 || v == out2);
```

Note: It is trivial to write a nested for loop to iterate over this structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, combine [`std::ranges::views::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view) with [`std::ranges::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) and some lambdas.

```
using namespace std::ranges::views;
auto to_pairs = [](auto & pair){ 
    auto to_pair = [&key=pair.first](auto & value){ return std::pair{ key, value }; };
    return pair.second | transform(to_pair); 
};
auto view = m | transform(to_pairs) | join | common;
```

Comment: I got a compiler error when trying to construct the vector from the view directly. 
 However, std::ranges::copy(view, std::back_inserter(v)) works great!

Comment: @MarkB oops, need to ensure the view is a `std::ranges::common_range`, see edit

Comment: Returning `std::pair<decltype(key), decltype(value)>{key, value}` is more efficient

Answer (score 5):

In C++23 you can use `views::cartesian_product`:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> m{
   {"Foo", {1,2}}, {"Hello", {4,5}}};
auto view = m | views::transform([](auto& p) {
         return views::cartesian_product(views::single(p.first), p.second); })
              | views::join;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n7ehMs6h3)